# Is there any template which can be used for both Logic Apps and Function Apps in azure CI/CD?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I want to implement CI/CD for both function apps and logic apps.

- Logic Apps:
  https://biztalkbox.wordpress.com/2019/02/16/ci-cd-for-azure-resourceseglogic-appsusing-azure-devops/
- Function Apps:
  https://dzone.com/articles/azure-function-build-release-pipeline-in-azure-dev

From above 2 posts, I understood that we have different templates for Azure functions and logic apps.So, 2 different build definitions needs to be created if we follow above posts.

I have logic apps and function apps in same develop branch.

Is there any way to create single build definition instead of multiple build definitions.

Comment: just combine them into a single yaml\old style definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to create single build definition instead of multiple
>   build definitions.

As the comment said, you can define these 2 different build definition in one Build pipeline by using **2 agent jobs**.

- **Build pipeline definition**:

[image]

**Note:** As you said, you stored `logic apps` and `function apps` in same develop branch. Please specified exactly on `Path to publish` when you run the `publish build artifact` task.

And then, you will see that it will generated 2 artifacts which for 2 different application.

[image]

---

- **Release pipeline definition**:

Since these are different app, please configure into **2** stages. One is for Logic app, and another is for Azuer function app:

[image]

The most important part is filter artifacts for corresponding stage. We just now generate 2 artifacts in one build pipeline. So here, we must filter out the corresponding artifacts and deploy it into the correct stage.

In the definition part of agent job, you can filter out the artifact by specifying as below shown:

[image]

Then configure the release task based on corresponding app artifact.